# Focus on buttons working in console, but not elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, focus

I have 4 buttons, that when clicked I am attempting to set focus on them, so the user can see which button is currently active.

For some reason it appears to be working in console as expected, when a button is clicked, it adds focus, changes background colour as per CSS, then when another button is clicked the first button loses focus, and the new one gains it.

When I don't have console open, it does not work.

```js
const oneYear = document.getElementById('1Year');
const fiveYear = document.getElementById('5Year');
const tenYear = document.getElementById('10Year');
const twentyYear = document.getElementById('20Year');

function changeDate(date) {

  if (date === 1) {
    oneYear.className += " active";
    setTimeout(oneYear.focus(), 1);
  }
  if (date === 5) {
    fiveYear.focus();
    fiveYear.className += " active";
  }
  if (date === 10) {
    tenYear.focus();
  }
  if (date === 20) {
    twentYear.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
.theme-dark-btn {
  transition: all ease 1s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #1ACC8D, #1ACC8D, #235FCD, #1C4CA3);
  background-size: 300%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #1C4CA3;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.theme-dark-btn:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
  border: 1px solid #1ACC8D;
}

.theme-dark-btn:focus {
  background-color: #1ACC8D;
}

.theme-dark-btn:active {
  background-color: #1ACC8D;
}

.btn {
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background-image .3s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.btn:focus {
  background-color: #1ACC8D;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" type="button" style="color: white" id="1Year" onclick="changeDate(1)" autofocus>1 Year</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="5Year" onclick="changeDate(5)">5 Years</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="10Year" onclick="changeDate(10)">10 Years</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="20Year" onclick="changeDate(20)">20 Years</button>
</div>
```

Comment: First your changeDate function has a mistake because   `twentYear` does not exists but i think it should be `twentyYear`.

Comment: Oops good find, but no doesn't resolve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you `click` the button you already make it `focused`, you don't need to make it `focus()` dynamically.

*So, why the background color doesn't change?*

**Because `background-image` already overrides the `background-color`**

**You need just set the `background` instead of `background-color`**

```
    .btn:focus {
        background: #1ACC8D;
    }
```

Full example without `JS`

```css
.theme-dark-btn {
  transition: all ease 1s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #1ACC8D, #1ACC8D, #235FCD, #1C4CA3);
  background-size: 300%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #1C4CA3;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.theme-dark-btn:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
  border: 1px solid #1ACC8D;
}

.theme-dark-btn:focus {
  background-color: #1ACC8D;
}

.theme-dark-btn:active {
  background-color: #1ACC8D;
}

.btn {
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background-image .3s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.btn:focus {
  background: #1ACC8D;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" type="button" style="color: white" id="1Year" autofocus>1 Year</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="5Year">5 Years</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="10Year">10 Years</button>
  <button class="btn theme-dark-btn" style="color: white" id="20Year">20 Years</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks that worked! Just a couple of follow up questions if possible!
1) Do you know why it would work with console open, but not with it closed? Made it hard to trouble shoot.
2) When I click the button now, it appears to turn the whole button white  for a brief second before getting focus, do you know what would cause that/how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: @LBJ33, you are welcome, 1) that's strange because that's wasn't work for me with opening the console or not, I just edit your question with codesnippet, please check again if it works if you open the console. 2) That also doesn't happen to me, in my case when I hover the button its background turns green and when clicked ( focused ) it stays as it is even if I hover out of it, it never turns white.

Comment: @LBJ33, I suggest you to use different browser and check again.